# Spring security authentication filter url ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

What I'm trying to accomplish is a jwt token-based authentication for my rest api.
Everything under /api should only be accessible with a token.

I have the following configure method in my web security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
    .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

And this is the filter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager manager) {
    super("/api/**");
    this.setAuthenticationManager(manager);
}

@Override
protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

    String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        throw new JwtTokenMissingException("No JWT token found in request headers");
    }

    String authToken = header.substring(7);

    JwtAuthenticationToken authRequest = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authToken);

    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

My problem is that the filter is now applied to every url, not just the ones with the /api prefix.

I'm aware of the fact that my "configure" method might be wrong, but what should it look like? All I want to accomplish is to use the filter for the /api path.

+1 question: why are there two values to configure the path to which the filter will be applied? (once as a parameter to the antMatchers method in the configuration, and then a constructor argument "filterProcessesUrl" for AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter). How do these values relate to each other, and which one should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this part:

```
@Override
protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return true;
}
```

I copied it and never realised it was there.

Comment: I think if you add `.antMatcher("/api/**")` before `.addFilterBefore` your problem will be solved too.